# xaml button on click adds another xaml panel in powershell

Tags: java, powershell, xaml

Similar to Android (I've done it before, with adding xml objects with java, in android, if you have any experience, as well) I mention that because I want to do something similar. By adding an XAML object into a XAML form, from PowerShell. I want to create a function, that can be called to dynamically add to the XAML form, programmatically.

```
[xml]xaml=@"
<Window>
    <Grid>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*">
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*">
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ToggleSwitch x:Name="toggleSwitch" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Image x:Name="<Name>" Source="<Source>" />
        <Image x:Name="<Name>" Source="<Source>" Visibility="Hidden" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@

$toggleSwitch = $syncHash.Window.FindName("toggleSwitch")
$toggleSwitch.Add_Click({*Change, the, image with a flick of a switch and "refresh" the window*})
```

This is actually another project, 2 combined into 1, but I'm not sure If I actually would need to refresh the window after the change/swap, but my other project, is "Similar", but instead of an image I want to dynamically/programmatically load a panel with the click of a button, and need it to "refresh" or "repaint" the window.

```
$add.Add_Click({
    function Add-Panel
    {
    [cmdletBinding()]
    Param()
        [xml]$xmlDoc = $xml
        $window = $xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Window")
        $grid = $window.Grid 
        $grids = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("Grid")
        $innerXml = @"
            <Grid Grid.Row="8">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Alternate DNS" FontWeight="Medium" />
            </Grid>

            <Grid Grid.Row="7">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBox x:Name="dns1" Width = "30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" MaxLength="3" />
                <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="." Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Medium"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="dns2" Width = "30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" MaxLength="3" />
                <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="." Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Medium"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="dns3" Width = "30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" MaxLength="3" />
                <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="." Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Medium"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="dns4" Width = "30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6" MaxLength="3" />
            </Grid>        
"@
    # } - Not knowing whether end of function goes here or below bottom code


        $grids.InnerXml = $innerXml
        $grid.AppendChild($grids)
        # $syncHash.Window.AddChild(@""@)

# Just some ideas I tried from seeing online.
        $syncHash.Window.Dispatcher.Invoke([action] { Add-Panel }, "Send")
        $syncHash.Window.Dispatcher.Invoke([action] { Add-Panel }, "Render")
    # } - or here..
})
```

I even tried..

```
    function Add-Panel
    {
    [cmdletBinding()]
    Param()
        [xml]$xmlDoc = $xml
        $window = $xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Window")
        $grid = $window.Grid 
        $grids = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("Grid")
        $innerXml = @"
            <Grid Grid.Row="8">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Alternate DNS" FontWeight="Medium" />
            </Grid>

            <Grid Grid.Row="7">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBox x:Name="dns1" Width = "30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" MaxLength="3" />
                <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="." Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Medium"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="dns2" Width = "30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" MaxLength="3" />
                <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="." Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Medium"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="dns3" Width = "30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" MaxLength="3" />
                <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="." Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Medium"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="dns4" Width = "30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6" MaxLength="3" />
            </Grid>        
"@

        $grids.InnerXml = $innerXml
        $grid.AppendChild($grids)
        # $syncHash.Window.AddChild(@""@)

# Just some ideas I tried from seeing online.
        $syncHash.Window.Dispatcher.Invoke([action] { Add-Panel }, 
            "Send")
        $syncHash.Window.Dispatcher.Invoke([action] { Add-Panel }, 
            "Render")
}

$add.Add_Click({
    Add-Panel
})
```

Comment: _"I want to create a function..."_ Sounds great. Please show us that function when you're done.

Comment: I got it done!! XD